# Adding User to Role Using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I have mocked up a `RoleManager` and `IdentityRoles`:

```
var roleList = new List<IdentityRole>()
{
    new IdentityRole { Name = "R1" },
    new IdentityRole { Name = "R2" },
};
mockRoleManager.Setup(m => m.Roles).Returns(roleList.AsQueryable<IdentityRole>);
```

I would like to add users to this role in the unit test. When I use

```
await userManager.Object.AddToRoleAsync(user, "R1");
```

it shows that the user was never added to the role during debugging. How can I populate roles during a unit test? I am using xUnit and Moq.

As suggested in the comments, I have tried setting up the `AddToRoleAsync` method, but with no luck. Below was how I tried to implement it:

```
//this will cause an error on the AddToRoleAsync method in the Act portion of the test
userManager.Setup(u => u.AddToRoleAsync(It.IsAny<AppUser>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(It.IsAny<Task<IdentityResult>>());
```

and also tried:

```
var identityResult = new Mock<Task<IdentityResult>>();
//this line gives an error 'Invalid setup on non-virtual (overridable in VB) member
identityResult.Setup(r => r.Result.Succeeded).Returns(true);
userManager.Setup(u => u.AddToRoleAsync(It.IsAny<AppUser>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(identityResult.Object);
```

Comment: You need to make sure you have mocked the RoleManager methods which would be called in AddToRoleAsync.

Comment: @FeiyuZhou I tried mocking the UserManager methods but without success. See my edits in the question

Comment: You need to use ReturnsAsync since the method return Task<IdentityResult>

Comment: @FeiyuZhou When I try `userManager.Setup(u => u.AddToRoleAsync(It.IsAny<AppUser>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(identityResult.Object);` the error is 'cannot convert from Task<IdentityResult> to System.Func<IdentityResult> (paraphrased)

Comment: The value cannot be `identityResult.Object`, it should be a real object. Or else you need to mock IdentityRole's methods and proerties called in your program.

Comment: @FeiyuZhou Should the first line with `It.IsAny<Task<IdentityResult>>()` not work then?

Comment: It.IsAny<T> is checking that the parameter is of type T, it can not be the mocked method's return value..